# TextEdit field input hangs on iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios10

Im experiencing very odd issue on iOS10 since rebuilding my few apps.
Every time i input more characters then it fits on screen in UITextField app just freeze and exactly nothing happens, there is no single error in debugger just frozen. After few minutes app crashes with memory issue.

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

I think it's something messed up with sizeToFit related to UITextField, as far i remember if text does not fits entirely in UITextField it gets smaller and then moves left.
Anyway issue happens only with `secureTextEntry = true` as it's password field. Apple messed up again with sdk, does anyone have any idea for workaround or better, fix on this?

Comment: If you can reproduce this with a simple app, then I'd recommend logging a bug in radar, and cc'ing openradar with the same.

Comment: Issue has been reported to apple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have resolved it with disabling Adjust to Fit for password field, but this is more workaround than fix.

Comment: where is "Adjust to Fit" option?

Comment: I believe the property David refers to is adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth (not tested yet)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth

Comment: `textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO`

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in iOS 10.2!