# iOS10: UITextfield hangs with long input when secureTextEntry

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, ios10

Strange behaviour from `UITextfield` with `secureTextEntry`.
Platform : iOS10
Both on iPhone (Device) and Simulator.
`UITextfield` hangs with long input which is greater than the keyboard's width, when `secureTextEntry` is on. The keyboard's pressed key stays popped out.

[image: Keyboard key stays popped out]

Comment: what do you mean by `"greater than the keyboard's width"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in SDK from Apple in iOS10.
I have resolved it with disabling Adjust to Fit for password field, (as per:

[TextEdit field input hangs on iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591770/textedit-field-input-hangs-on-ios10) )

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is a bug.

Bug is like :

> An app can freeze when a user types a large password into a textfield that tries to scale down the text to fit.

Check it : https://openradar.appspot.com/28590124

Possible solution :
Disable to Fit for password/secured field.

1. [change the secure password character in UITextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280069/change-the-secure-password-character-in-uitextfield/3280471#3280471)
2. [Secure UITextField text change to (*) asterisk character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006499/secure-uitextfield-text-change-to-asterisk-character?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I already mention the trick in possible solution section with more information. Think my one is best answer between two of this.

Answer (score 1):

This has finally been fixed in iOS 10.2!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in iOS 10.0.2... https://openradar.appspot.com/28590124

I have resolved it with disabling Adjust to Fit for password field, but this is more workaround than fix.

this bug fixed in 10.2